# push a view controller from a UIView ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation based application.On click of a button on the navigation bar in the first screen , I am able to push another view controller as follows :

```
 -(void) buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

    UIViewController*  mv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:mv animated:YES];  

}
```

Now i have a UIView(separate .h and .m files) as part of the first screen. On click of a button in the UIView, i want to push the SecondViewController. 
I have tried the following :

```
 UIViewController*  mv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
 UIViewController * home=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
 [[home navigationController] pushViewController:mv animated:YES];
```

It doesnt work!! Kindly help

Comment: Try [self.navigationController popToRootViewController animated:YES];

Comment: UIView doesn't have a "navigationController" property.

Comment: The elephant in the room is: What in the hell is this UIView contained in?  You can't push a UIView onto the stack without a container...  And it's SOOO much easier to just contain his first view in a UIViewController or a UINavigationController and layer that over the main window at startup than to just lay a UIView over it...

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController*  mv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController * home=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
[[home navigationController] pushViewController:mv animated:YES];
```

The problem here is that `home` isn't part of the navigation stack, so `[home navigationController]` is surely nil. I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do here, but just creating a view controller doesn't mean that it's actually part of the view controller graph.

Comment: home is part of the navigation stack...because on click of a button directly on home.view, i am able to navigate to second view.
The problem is when i click a button on a UIView i am unable to navigate

Comment: @user930514 Not in the code you provided, and which I've quoted above. On line 2 you allocate and initialize a FirstViewController and assign that to `home`. That controller is clearly not part of any nav stack, so calling `navigationController` will yield nil. Try adding `UINavigationController *nav = [home navigationController];` after the second line and check the value of nav in the debugger to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it work? Randomly creating view controllers whose view is not even visible, is not the solution. You can either keep a reference to the VC in the view like this:

```
@imlementation ViewController

- (id) init
{
    // ...
    aView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
    aView.viewController = self;
    // ...
}

@end

@interface CustomView

@property (assign) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Or you can search the responder chain at runtime:

```
UIResponder *next = [view nextResponder];
while (next)
{
    if ([next isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])
    {
        break;
    }
    next = [next nextResponder];
}
```

And now "next" will contain the view controller (or nil if it can't be found).

Comment: What do u mean by randomly creating view controllers whose view is not visible? All Views are visible and we have just 2 view controllers..First and Second. The UIView occupies a part of the first screen

Comment: The statement aView.viewController = self cannot be written. It gives an error. Even @property(assign) ViewController *viewController gives an error...saying Unknown ViewController..I tried importing ViewController.h but it gives other errors

Comment: I mean, if you create a view controller with no relation to the navigaiton stack, responder chain, etc., then it won't work, as the parent view controller knows nothing about it.

Comment: gosh, didn't you understand that it's an *example*? Of course you'll need to substitute your own view controller class name to ViewController...

Comment: The view controller has relation to the navigation stack...because when we click on a button directly on home.view , it navigates!!

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem now!  You need to #import your FirstViewController, then @class it.  Then do your push.

So:

```
//.h 
#import "FirstViewContoller.h"

@class FirstViewController;

@interface...

//.m

-(void)return {
FirstViewController *firstview = [[FirstViewController alloc]init(withnibname:)];
[firstView.navigationController pushViewController: firstView.navigationController.topViewController animated: TRUE];
}
```

Comment: UIView DOES NOT have a navigationController property!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same navigationController to push view, this keeps  the same stack of ViewControllers.

```
UIViewController*  mv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:mv animated:YES]; 

[mv release];
```

Comment: UIView doesn't have a navigationController property.

Comment: Wait, why is he pushing a UIView?? secondViewController is a UIViewController, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, your UIView though is in separate files, is still added to the screen from a UIViewController class.

Simply, post a notification from UIView to your FirstViewController class where you have access to the navigation controller. Then push the SecondViewController from there.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this. It Works very well for me:-

Firstly Create Object of AppDelegate in UIView Class and initialize it. Then create Navigationcontroller object in Appdelegate.h :-

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navControl;
```

In your UIView Class implement this code where you want to push :-

```
ViewController *objview = [[ViewController alloc]init]; [appDelegate.navControl pushViewController:objview animated:YES];
```